How much were they per trouser? (in the context of trousers)
Two Brits are talking about a few pairs of new trousers. One of them bought a few pairs and is showing his friend by trying them on, as his friend is making comments about each pair (color, look, size etc). At one point, his friend asked:
How much were they per trouser? Getting a fashion show (see:3:05-3:13)
This question sounded different to me, because I have never heard "per trouser". So, I wonder is it correct usage? We were told to always use "trousers". So, if "per trouser" is not correct usage, would "How much were they per pair" be correct?

How much were they each?

Where did you hear/read this conversation? To speak of 'a trouser' is decidedly odd; I've only occasionally heard it used humorously to refer to one trouser leg.

@KateBunting, I heard it on a video on youtube and I put the link in the text above.

The standard way of talking about garments for the legs is as 'pairs' (e.g. of trousers or jeans). However, some people (and not just Brits) especially those who work in clothes-related jobs, or who are very interested in clothes and fashion may talk of 'a trouser',  'a jean', 'a pant', etc (I've never heard 'a short', but I gather others have).
A (UK) Guardian fashion writer:

Elizabeth Radcliffe is Levi’s master tailor, and if you have £750 to
spend she will bring her Savile Row training to creating a bespoke
pair of jeans in her Soho atelier just for you. She knows more than
probably anyone else about the tweaks and tricks that make jeans work,
and a while ago I spent an illuminating half an hour trying on jeans
with her, and downloading her wisdom to share with you.
It turns out that the most flattering rise of waistband, on me and on
lots of women, is neither a low-rise nor a rib-kissing high waistband,
but one that sits about an inch below the belly button at the front
and curves up and away at the sides to sit slightly higher at the
back, so that it hooks over your hipbones and doesn’t gape. Also, a
mid to heavyweight of denim works best on most women, with just enough
give that the silhouette can hug a curve but with enough structure to
belt you in around the waist. And I learned that the lowest point of
the back pocket should sit slightly above the crease at the top of
your leg, to create a visual distinction between bottom and thigh.
Lizzie had me sitting down and standing up, shoes on and off, hem up
or under, to figure out which leg shape and length worked best. I
prefer a jean that releases from the leg, so straight styles work for
me; if you like denim that clings to your shape, you will want a
skinny or bootcut.

Note: 750 UK pounds is, in round figures, 1,000 US dollars.
Your Perfect Jeans do Exist (Guardian 14 April 2023)
Websites belonging to jeans companies often talk of 'a jean'.

Yoke: The section of a jean directly under the waistband (Levi's web site)

It is definitely not standard English and I suggest you avoid it.
would "How much were they per pair" be correct? Yes, definitely.

a pair of jeans or jeans, in AmE, always. Those websites have SEO deficiencies. https://www.levi.com/US/en_US/clothing/men/jeans/c/levi_clothing_men_jeans?srsltid=AfmBOopVm1zp9jK4Ht_v2HaQfd3O6ZVj7ofx-32-RsTwrSv9PfP2YIKn
